# Get JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript

I am working client side on a web page that I am unable to edit.

I want to use JS to click on a particular button, but it does not have a unique identifier.

I do know the class and I do know a (unique) string in the innerHTML that I can match with, so I am iterating through the (varying number) of buttons with a while loop looking for the string:

```
var theResult = '';
var buttonNum = 0;
var searchString = '720p';
while (theResult.indexOf(searchString) == -1
{
  theResult = eval(\"document.getElementsByClassName('streamButton')[\" + buttonNum + \"].innerHTML\");
  buttonNum++;
}
```

Now I should know the correct position in the array of buttons (buttonNum-1, I think), but how do I reference this?  I have tried:

```
eval(\"document.getElementsByClassName('streamButton')[\" + buttonNum-1 + \"].click()")
```

and variation on the position of ()'s in the eval, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you got a down vote for, seems like a pretty valid question. Though I'm unsure of a couple things. You say you're unable to edit the page, are you just running this javascript in your browser console? Is there a reason you need to do this?

Comment: Yes I am running it locally and it's because I am trying to get to some data that's only available on the page loaded by clicking on this button.

Comment: Why do you use eval?

Comment: Because I thought I needed to do this to get the concatenated string interpreted.

Comment: Absolutely not. This works : `document.getElementsByClassName('streamButton')[buttonNum].innerHTML`

Comment: In general, **avoid using `eval()`** unless *all* other possibilities have been exhausted.

Comment: Thank you all. I have dropped the eval(), but the question still remains about how to refer to the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the eval, but you can check all the buttons one by one and just click the button immediately when you find it so you don't have to find it again.

It is not as elegant as what @Shilly suggested, but probably more easily understood if you are new to javascript.

```js
var searchString = '720p';
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("streamButton"); // find all streamButtons
if(buttons)
{
   // Search all streamButtons until you find the right one
   for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
   {
      var button = buttons[i];
      var buttonInnerHtml = button.innerHTML;
      if (buttonInnerHtml.indexOf(searchString) != -1) {
        button.click();
        break;
      }
  }
}

function allOtherClick() {
  console.log("Wrong button clicked");
}

function correctButtonClick() {
  console.log("Right button clicked");
}
```

```html
<button class='streamButton' onclick='allOtherClick()'>10</button>
<button class='streamButton' onclick='allOtherClick()'>30</button>
<button class='streamButton' onclick='correctButtonClick()'>720p</button>
<button class='streamButton' onclick='allOtherClick()'>abcd</button>
```

Comment: I think I am going to get this more than the other answer for the reason you suggest (because I am new to JS).  I have got a couple of questions: the line: var button = document.getElementsByClassName('streamButton')[" + buttonNum + "]"; seems a bit confused about concatenation.  Is this how you meant to write it? Also, the searchString is contained in the innerHTML, so not the same length as it, so I have disposed of that check.

Comment: @Lorccan You are right, I must have mangled the javascript right before I posted it. I've updated it to fix it (and removed that exact match check since it isn't what you wanted). 
If this is the answer you go with, please accept it. :) 
If there is something else I'm missing let me know!

Comment: @Lorccan Actually I looked at the answer again and I fixed it to use a simple `for` loop. Last time I was fetching all the buttons over and over for no reason.

Comment: Thanks.  That works and I understand what's happening!

Answer (score 4):

You could try something like:

```
var searchStr = '720p',
    // Grab all buttons that have the class 'streambutton'.
    buttons = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('button.streamButton')),
    // Filter all the buttons and select the first one that has the sreachStr in its innerHTML.
    buttonToClick = buttons.filter(function( button ) {
        return button.innerHTML.indexOf(searchStr) !== -1;
    })[0];
```

Comment: Can you add in the code that would actually click the button as well?

Comment: just add `buttonToClick.click()` at the end

Comment: Thank you.  I went with the other solution because it was more clear for my level of JS, but I will research your code to make sure I 'get it'.

Answer (score 0):

I would stay clear of eval here, what if the text on the button is some malicious javaScript?

Can you use jQuery? if so, check out [contains](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/). You can use it like so:

```
$(".streamButton:contains('720p')")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use standard JS.